# prop passed to component return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have asynchronous method get called and I need the value from it to be render on the first cycle so it will be passed to the next component that being render and I cant make id done. The component is rendered before the value is returned which cause the the prop be `undefined` when it passed.
Any idea how can I delay the rendering till the value get returned?

CODE SAMPLE:

```
export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            valueHere:''
        }
    }


componentWillMount() {
    axios.post(url, {
        username:this.state.username
    })
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
            valueHere:res.data
        })
    })
}    


    render() {
        return(
            <AnotherComponent
            someValue={this.state.valueHere}
        />
        )
    }

}


export default class AnotherComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }



    render() {
        console.log(this.props.someValue) // undefined
        return(
            <View/>
        )
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).
So basically, you check if that value exists then render the component else return null/any other component;

```
render() {
return( this.props.someValue? <ActualComponeent /> : <div> some loader...</div>)
}
```

Comment: it wont work for me as I need it to be rendered anyway because there would be times this value will be undefined anyway and I need the component to be rendered those times as well

Comment: then use this same code there, instead of returning null, return any default component. @obiwankenoobi updated the code

Comment: but then it will just return the default component.  The call is made > *no response yet* > default component rendered > response is back > component already rendered with an empty prop

Comment: Nope..as you are calling the `setState` method, it will be re-rendered with response from api so at that time it will render `ActualComponent`

Comment: This is where loaders get displayed. I see the code in question is doing an API call which will usually be fetching some data. So the dummy component in the answer above can be a loader. <div >calling api ...</div>.